# Download m3u8 segments with ffmpeg without writing the .ts files to disk

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying to download m3u8 segments from an HLS live stream with ffmpeg without writing the .ts files to disk. I intend to run opencv on the image data in real time. Here is what I have tried, but I am only able to get one segment at a time and don't know how to just keep it in memory without writing to disk. When inspecting the network requests using developer tools on the Twitch site, I see the m3u8's arriving in real time, although, these don't work in the script. I have to refresh the page and get the URL of the first request that arrives, which is a URL not ending in .m3u8 (the one i'm using in the script)

```
import requests
import m3u8

url = 'https://usher.ttvnw.net/api/channel/hls/gernaderjake.m3u8?allow_source=true&fast_bread=true&p=4466372&play_session_id=d66db58de3bf6be70a5f5824bbb72763&player_backend=mediaplayer&playlist_include_framerate=true&reassignments_supported=true&sig=2b97079328898fdae56b041616be6fc7b01bd13c&supported_codecs=avc1&token=%7B%22adblock%22%3Afalse%2C%22authorization%22%3A%7B%22forbidden%22%3Afalse%2C%22reason%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22blackout_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22channel%22%3A%22gernaderjake%22%2C%22channel_id%22%3A1423946%2C%22chansub%22%3A%7B%22restricted_bitrates%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22view_until%22%3A1924905600%7D%2C%22ci_gb%22%3Afalse%2C%22geoblock_reason%22%3A%22%22%2C%22device_id%22%3A%22ec6cb1f95615ed0b%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1618772589%2C%22extended_history_allowed%22%3Afalse%2C%22game%22%3A%22%22%2C%22hide_ads%22%3Afalse%2C%22https_required%22%3Atrue%2C%22mature%22%3Afalse%2C%22partner%22%3Afalse%2C%22platform%22%3A%22web%22%2C%22player_type%22%3A%22site%22%2C%22private%22%3A%7B%22allowed_to_view%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22privileged%22%3Afalse%2C%22role%22%3A%22%22%2C%22server_ads%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_ads%22%3Atrue%2C%22subscriber%22%3Afalse%2C%22turbo%22%3Afalse%2C%22user_id%22%3Anull%2C%22user_ip%22%3A%22173.22.40.125%22%2C%22version%22%3A2%7D&cdm=wv&player_version=1.3.0'

r = requests.get(url)

m3u8_master = m3u8.loads(r.text)

playlist_url = m3u8_master.data['playlists'][0]['uri']

r = requests.get(playlist_url)

playlist = m3u8.loads(r.text)

playlist.data['segments'][0]['uri']

r = requests.get(playlist.data['segments'][0]['uri'])

with open('video.ts', 'wb') as f:
    for segment in playlist.data['segments']:
        url = segment['uri']
        r = requests.get(url)
        f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: I know nothing about the segments and URL issues, but you may try decoding the video frames without writing to disk as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332694/display-stream-with-ffmpeg-python-and-opencv).