# Using FFMPEG in OpenCV for reading frames from rtsp camera

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am writing a small script in python3.8 to read frames from a rtsp camera. The code is as follows:

```
import cv2 
gst_out =  "rtsp://admin:psw@IP:88/videoMain"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_out, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print("New Frame")
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, cap is never opened and i do not understand why. I am using opencv 4.5.2 in ubuntu 20.04. This is what i get when i call `cv2.getBuildInformation()`:

```
 Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.2)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

So as you can see FFMPEG is available. In fact, when i execute `ffmpeg` in terminal, i get the following:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

Could you tell me what could be wrong? I have tested the IP in the browser and everything is working properly.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but I noticed that in your opencv build `avresample` is marked `NO`. In my environment (using opencv 4.5.5) it is marked `YES (4.0.0)`.

Comment: For testing if your OpenCV supports RTSP protocol, I recommend testing with public RTSP: `gst_out =  "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4"`. In case it's working, the issue is probably related to the camera. From time to time there is a question about failing to grab frames from RTSP camera using OpenCV. Instead of using OpenCV, you may use FFmpeg CLI, as in my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66341885/4926757).

Comment: @wohlstad, i thought this could be the problem however it seems that this library is deprecated

Comment: @Rotem, it works with the public RTSP. It is quite weird because i tested my code in Windows and it worked but not in ubuntu

Comment: @Rotem, the camera is with PoE instead of direct Ethernet connection. Could this affect?

Comment: Assuming the same configuration is working with Windows, it is probably not related to PoE. Did you try the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66341885/4926757) using FFmpeg CLI?

Comment: Does running `ffprobe rtsp://admin:psw@IP:88/videoMain` shows anything?